# Angular 5 issue with contenteditable and input in firefox and safari

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firefox, angular5

So I'm creating a table with content-editable cells, I need at the same time to update the visual and the typescript code, unfortunately all alternatives I found didn't work, here is a plunker with identical issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/PCXNFSUqiHrYedx4E4mW?p=preview

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div contenteditable='true'
         (input)='name=$event.target.innerText' 
         [(innerText)]='name'>
      name
    </div>
    <br>
    <div contenteditable='true'
         (input)='name=$event.target.innerHtml' 
         [(innerHtml)]='name'>
      name
    </div>
    <br>
    <div contenteditable='true'
         (input)='name=$event.target.textContent' 
         [(textContent)]='name'>
      name
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

It works well with google chrome and opera, safari and mozilla wrights the text backwards with textContent and innerText, and the value become undefined with innerHtml.

@Update

For my issue I end up using input-field inside the cells

```
<td [class.active]="selectedCell.row === rowIndex && selectedCell.colunm === 3"
          (click)="setSelectedCell(rowIndex, 3, true)"
          class="lassoer-info">
        <input [id]="'entity' + rowIndex"
               (keydown)="onkeyDown($event)"
               [(ngModel)]="rowData.entity"
               [disabled]="rowData.inscriptionId || !canEdit"
               type="text"
               class="input-field">
</td>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in chrome either

Comment: sorry there was a miss type in the plunker, but you are correct, innerHtml and innerText also don't work on chrome, but textContent do.

Comment: Your plunker shows "Angular! v5.2.7" three times in both Chrome and Firefox on my Win10 laptop.

Comment: first one with innerHtml, second innerHtml and third textContent.

Comment: They are all editable. Sorry that i coundnt provide a better plunker, but i'm really in a hurry in my personal life, and since this is a minor problem in my job i'm prioritizing other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting with Angular but I think I can spot one mistake. In Javascript it should be innerHTML instead of innerHtml (HTML in upper case).

Comment: In webstorm ide when I type innerHTML in uppercase it says its an unsolved variable. And if I compile with it when typing in the contenteditable cell it types backwards in all browsers.